# How to write string with 3 significant digits without rounding

Tags: java, string, digits, significant-digits

I would like the convert string value with 3 significant digits.

I am using this code :

```
String s = "0,92";
float f = Float.parseFloat(s);
DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#,###");
String end = formatter.format(f);
```

The result is end= 0.000. But ı want to get end = 0,920. How can i do that?

Comment: you really mean to get `,` instead of `.`?

Comment: Yes sorry. I edited the question.

Comment: As Jonjongot hinted, You should change the comma in the original value ("0,92") to a period - only then parseFloat will be able to convert the string to a float and let the formatting work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If in your current locale the decimal separator is a dot then you will get 0.920. If you want to get the result independent from you current locale to have as decimal separator a comma and as thousand separator a dot you could achieve it for example like this

```
String s = "0.92";
float f = Float.parseFloat(s);
DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("0.000", DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance(Locale.GERMANY));
String end = formatter.format(f);
System.out.println("end = " + end);
```

This prints

```
 end = 0,920
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
String s = "0.92";
float f = Float.parseFloat(s);
DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("0.000");
String end = formatter.format(f);
System.out.println(end);
```

Please note the '.' in the String s and the pattern in DecimalFormat.
 
',' here means the 1000 marker, ie. 1,000,000.00 for one million.